# Github API: Remote host closed the connection before initiating inbound response

Tags: http, curl, github, networking, throttling

I am working on an application which iterates through an array of github repositories and identifies which github users (stored in a separate table)have not starred each repositories.

An equivalent curl request would look like follows.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/<GITHUB_REPOSITORY>/stargazers?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Above will return 30 github users per page who have starred the repository and we can increase it to a maximum of 100 per page as follows

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/<GITHUB_REPOSITORY>/stargazers?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>/?page=<PAGE_NUMBER>&per_page=100
```

For example if a repo has 540 stars, I am iterating 6 times to get the list of github usernames who have starred. This is working all fine for repositories with less number of stars (say less than 5000). However with the number of stars increasing I fear it might run into network problems like throttling. I ran the program with a repo with 100,000+ stars (even though my requirement is comparatively less)and it returned this error.

```
ERROR - Remote host closed the connection before initiating inbound response"
```

Can someone please tell me what is the most optimal way to get the list of github usernames without running into networks.